# Fill up space in ImageButton in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

[image]

What is wrong with my setting? I want to fill up all the content in `ImageButton`. Tried to set all margin to 0 but did not help.

[image]

`scaleType`: `centerCrop`

`cropToPadding`: true

`adjustViewBound`: true

What else I need?

Comment: Are you sure there is no padding, please post xml code for the ImageButton.

Comment: try taking imageview instead of image button and see if space appears still

Comment: But I need touch event, possible w ImageView?

Comment: Yes ImageView are clickable too, basically all views are clickable, and you can trigger touch event.

Comment: @János you you can have touch events with imageviews, imagebuttons some times defaultly provide some borders

Comment: @János are you using  android:src to set the image. Because if I set the image via background this issue not replicating. But using src this issue persists.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb u are right w `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Did you noticed that, in your screenshot, style value is 'imageButtonStyle', that may contains some styling causing this...

Also, you have a **background** which is 'btn_default_material...'.
Just clean this background an see if it help. This could be the **first think to check**.

Finally, and it's ***really really important about coding best practices***, I hope your app is showing respect to girls and ladies ;-)

Blurring faces would be a good thing to do on this image.

Answer (score 0):

set scaleType to fitXY

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```